# Netbeans 6.9.1 on Windows fails to run with the error below when using ArrayList object

Tags: java, windows, glassfish-3, netbeans-6.9, corba

When I execute code using ArrayList object on Windows with Netbeans 6.9.1 and Glassfishv3,
it fails and spits the error below. If I comment out the ArrayList, everything works fine.

**Appreciate your help!**

```
Jan 11, 2011 12:31:29 PM com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified initDelegates
INFO: Using com.sun.enterprise.transaction.jts.JavaEETransactionManagerJTSDelegate as the delegate
Today = 11/03/2010
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.AppClientContainer.launch(AppClientContainer.java:424)
        at org.glassfish.appclient.client.AppClientFacade.launch(AppClientFacade.java:151)
        at org.glassfish.appclient.client.AppClientGroupFacade.main(AppClientGroupFacade.java:64)
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA MARSHAL 1398079745 Maybe; nested exception is: 
        org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: ----------BEGIN server-side stack trace----------
org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 257 completed: Maybe
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.couldNotFindClass(ORBUtilSystemException.java:10144)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.couldNotFindClass(ORBUtilSystemException.java:10159)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1163)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:986)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_abstract_interface(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:978)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_abstract_interface(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:968)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_abstract_interface(CDRInputObject.java:691)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.readObjectDelegate(IIOPInputStream.java:402)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.readObjectOverride(IIOPInputStream.java:577)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:345)
        at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:593)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.invokeObjectReader(IIOPInputStream.java:1965)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1300)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:449)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:364)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:320)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readRMIIIOPValueType(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1066)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1175)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_value(CDRInputObject.java:655)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectField(IIOPInputStream.java:2298)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputClassFields(IIOPInputStream.java:2552)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1310)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:449)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:364)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:320)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readRMIIIOPValueType(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1066)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1175)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_value(CDRInputObject.java:655)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl$14.read(DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.java:383)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.readArguments(DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.java:453)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie._invoke(ReflectiveTie.java:174)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:682)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:216)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1841)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1695)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1078)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:221)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:797)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:561)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.doWork(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:2558)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:492)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:528)

----------END server-side stack trace----------  vmcid: SUN  minor code: 257 completed: Maybe
        at com.enchronize.activitystream.ejb._FeedFacadeRemote_Wrapper.create(com/enchronize/activitystream/ejb/_FeedFacadeRemote_Wrapper.java)
        at activitystream.Main.createFeed(Main.java:75)
        at activitystream.Main.main(Main.java:37)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA MARSHAL 1398079745 Maybe; nested exception is: 
        org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: ----------BEGIN server-side stack trace----------
org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 257 completed: Maybe
```

Answer (score 0):

try java Packages from Jar finder or Class Search to proper jar or class for arrayList. It may Help.